# Difference between permutation groups and galois groups?

Tags: galois-theory

A124938   Number of non-solvable transitive Galois groups for polynomials of degree n.   +40
1

0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 15, 4, 35, 3, 27, 40, 49, 5, 91, 2, 358 (list; graph; refs; listen; history; text; internal format)

A198342   Number of non-solvable transitive permutation groups for polynomials of degree n.   +40
1

0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 3, 5, 4, 21, 4, 36, 3, 27, 40, 49, 5, 91, 2, 358, 56, 27, 3, 807, 79, 26, 64, 617, 2, 1896, 4 (list; graph; refs; listen; history; text; internal format)

I wanted to write down the non-solvable galoisgroups of polynomials. At degree
 10, there are, according to OEIS, 15 non-solvable galois-groups, but 21
 permutation groups. What is the difference ? What about the 6 permutation
 groups which are not galois-groups ?

Comment: As the text says, they *do* operate transitively on a set of $n$ points, but it is not possible to take the roots of a polynomial as these points and extend the permutations to field automorphisms ...

Answer (score 0):

A124938 is wrong. According to the text, it should be given by subtracting A002106 from A124937, but when we do that for the 10th terms we get $45-24=21$ (the correct value) and not $15$.